# How to use "DEGREE" in my iOS application

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

Hi I need to make a 2D arch. Where I am getting a problem here

```
arc.path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(50, 100)
                                                  radius:80.0
                                                  startAngle:DEGREE(65)
                                                  endAngle:DEGREE(90)
                                                  clockwise:NO].CGPath;
```

I am getting an error that

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_DEGREE", referenced from:`

**I know I have not included some header file, May I know which one is to include?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DEGREE` is macro, not a method!!!

As you can easily guess by its name. **Naming conventions come into play**

You have to define it might be as :

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

or

```
#define DEGREE(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

Comment: I prefer RADIANS_FROM_DEGREES()

Answer (score 7):

It should be custom macro you can also declare yourself and give it to your name. Try as following, put it anywhere in your header or implementation file.

```
#define DEGREE(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works for you...

```
(CGFloat) radians:(CGFloat) degrees
{
    CGFloat angle = degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
    return angle;
}
```

@Matthias Bauch: Thanks for the info.

Comment: no need to redefine M_PI with something less accurate. M_PI is defined in math.h already.